# Verification of the normalization of a wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, probability, normalization

A particle in an l-dimensional box is described by the wavefunction

[image]

Probability density = 1 to be normalized but I can't proceed from the last step
$$P= 1 - (1/L) (\sin 2n\pi\cos 2n\pi)$$ to equal to 1 to show that it normalized?

Comment: If $n$ is an integer, what is $\sin(2n\pi)$?

Comment: then it become sin(2nπ)= 0

Comment: @SeanE.Lake why we only think about integers, why it can't get fractions? so If we get fraction sin(2nπ) is not equal to 0.

Comment: What does $\psi(x)$ equal? What conditions does it have to satisfy (probably at $\psi(0)$ and $\psi(L)$)? Does the requirement that the wave function satisfy those equations limit what $n$ can be?